# Android FacebookAPI - newMeRequest never returns to onCompleted

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I started off by following the facebook API for Android tutorial and have hit an odd problem.  On pre-ICS devices, the code works and facebook login works correctly, but doesn't work on newer devices because it never returns to onComplete.

```
private void fbAuthentication() {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.d("DEBUG", "Facebook user ID: " + user.getId());
                        }
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The initial code that I got from the facebook tutorial was using deprecated code, so I don't know why they have that on their official developer page, but I have since changed it to "newMeRequest" as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I've run this code on a post ICS device without any issues. I don't think you have an open session. Because of this

> if (session.isOpened())

the request will only be sent for open sessions. Do checks to see where the execution is actually stopping

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
             Log.e("My Unique App TAG","The session is open. Sending newMeRequest");
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.d("DEBUG", "Facebook user ID: " + user.getId());
                        }
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
           else{
            Log.e("My Unique App TAG","Session is NOT open");
              } 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the above code working by ensuring that it's run on the Main Thread